# Управление USB через Android

Tags: android, android-studio, usb

В интернете нашел такой код:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap < String, UsbDevice > deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");
        Log.e("asdadsdas",device.getDeviceName());
    }
}
```

Хочу понять как отправлять сигнал и принимать его по usb контроллеру.

Код останавливается на строчке

```
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");
```

с исключением:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Я как понял device  не создан, так как usb не определен. Но он подключен и комп видит его.

[Материал взял отсюда](http://microsin.net/programming/android/usb-host.html)

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то не у каждого устройства есть поддержка USB-OTG. Может быть вашe как раз и не поддерживает, вот и выбрасывается `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, Там написано для этого надо в манифесте прописать.
вот это. <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>. Но я не понимаю одного.Класс android.hardware.usb есть. А host там нет. Может из за этого?

В манифесте указал АПИ 12

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы планшет видел ваше устройство, надо права *usb-otg*, они должны быть подправлены с помощью приложения usb (диагностика), которое работает под рутом.